# Case statement with two cases together

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, case

I have a scenario where I have multiple occurrences of `Emp` in a table. I want to return a string `Context` depending on these conditions:

If for one `Emp`

- Dep_no in (10,11,12) only => 'FTB'
- Dep_no in (22,23) only => 'SD'
- Dep_no in (10,11,12) and in (22,23) => 'IT'

The 3rd condition can match, because `Dep_no` can be in these two sets in different records for the same `Emp`.

How can I implement the third case using a case statement or any other solution in SQL server 2016?

For example an
Employee has Dep_No in 10 and 22 (yellow example), he should be IT

Employee has 10 and/or 11 he should be FTB

Employee has 22 and/or 23 then he should be SD

**Data in table look like below**

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Small item.   It is case expression not statement.

Comment: How can `Dep_no` be *both* `IN (10,11,12)` and `IN (22,23)`? Presumably `Dep_no` is a column, and thus represents a **scalar** value; it's therefore *impossible* for those 2 `IN`s to *both* be true. If `Dep_no` has the value `10`, for example, it by definition isn't the value `22` or `23`.

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN EXISTS(...) AND EXISTS(...)`

Comment: @Larnu: OP's image is pretty self-explanatory, it's about the employee which has multiple `Dep_No`

Comment: @TimSchmelter that image was added *after* my comment. As much as I would love to be able to, I *can't* see data the OP hadn't provided (yet). :)

Comment: What is `FTB`, `SD` and `IT`? Are these other columns or strings to be returned? If these are department types, the best would be to store these types in the department table where you can lookup this type: `SELECT m.Emp, m.Dep_No, d.DepType FROM myTable m INNER JOIN department d ON m.Dep_No = d.Dep_No`.

Comment: FTB, SD and IT are strings to be returned for Column "Context". They are not department Types.

Comment: @Isha `SELECT Emp, CASE WHEN Dep_Code < 1 THEN 'FTB' WHEN Dep_Code % 1 = 0 THEN 'SD' ELSE 'IT' END AS Dep_Name FROM (SELECT Emp, SUM(CASE WHEN Dep_No IN (10,11,12) THEN 0.1 -- 'FTB' WHEN Dep_No IN (22,23) THEN 1.0 -- 'SD' END) AS Dep_Code FROM TableName GROUP BY Emp) Dep_Codes;`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Thing (
    Emp    int NOT NULL,
    Dep_No int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Thing (Emp, Dep_No)
VALUES 
    (123, 10),
    (123, 11),
    (455, 22),
    (455, 23),
    (566, 10),
    (566, 22)

SELECT e.Emp,
    CASE 
        WHEN ftb.Emp IS NOT NULL AND sd.Emp IS NOT NULL THEN 'IT'
        WHEN ftp.Emp IS NOT NULL AND sd.Emp IS     NULL THEN 'FTB'
        WHEN ftb.Emp IS     NULL AND sd.Emp IS NOT NULL THEN 'SD'
        ELSE '?'
    END AS NewThing
FROM (
    -- PK of the result table.
    SELECT DISTINCT Emp FROM Thing
) AS e
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- Lookup case FTB.
        SELECT DISTINCT Emp FROM Thing WHERE Dep_No IN (10, 11, 12)
    ) AS ftb
        ON e.Emp = ftb.Emp
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- Lookup case SD.
        SELECT DISTINCT Emp FROM Thing WHERE Dep_No IN (22, 23)
    ) AS sd
        ON e.Emp = sd.Emp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with nested SELECTs. The inner SELECT counts the number of times a `Dep_no` is in one the two sets of numbers. The outer SELECT then returns the desired string based on these counts.

```sql
SELECT
   Emp,
   CASE WHEN g1>0 AND g2>0 THEN 'IT'
        WHEN g1>0 THEN 'FTB'
        WHEN g2>0 THEN 'SD'
   END AS Context
FROM (
   SELECT
      Emp,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Dep_No IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS g1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Dep_No IN (22, 23) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS g2
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY Emp
) g
```

With this example table

```sql
create table myTable (
  Emp int,
  Dep_No int
);
insert into MyTable (Emp, Dep_No) VALUES (123,10), (123,11), (455, 22), (455, 23), (566, 10), (566, 22);
```

We get this result

| Emp | Context |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | FTB |
| 455 | SD |
| 566 | IT |

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/339814/3/0